# Как показывать только те блоки, которые с классом его атрибута?

Tags: javascript

Есть рабочий скрипт, который показывает определенные блоки при выборе значения из выпадающего списка. По умолчанию показывает все блоки, но если поставить selected="selected" не для all, а для второго или третьего значения, все равно по умолчанию показывает все блоки, а мне нужно чтобы показывало только те, которые с классом его атрибута.

```js
$(function() {

var newSelection = ""; 

$("#flavor-nav").on('change', function(){
  $("#all-flavors").fadeTo(200, 0.10);

  $("#flavor-nav option").removeClass("current");
  $("#flavor-nav option:selected").addClass("current");

  newSelection = $("#flavor-nav option:selected").attr("bubu");

  $(".flavor").not("." + newSelection).slideUp();
  $("." + newSelection).slideDown();

  $("#all-flavors").fadeTo(600, 1);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="all-flavors">
  <select id="flavor-nav">
    <option bubu="all" selected="selected">All</option> 
    <option bubu="cla">Classic</option> 
    <option bubu="adv">Adventurous</option> 
    <option bubu="tea">Tea-Inspired</option> 
  </select>
  <div class="flavor all adv">
    <h4>Sweet Curry With Saffron</h4>
    <p>Lusciously mellow with notes of overripe berries, 55% Hawaiian dark chocolate meets its soulmate in sweet curry - awash in spices including coriander, tumeric, cumin and cardamom and sprinkled with rare saffron. This spicy melange is slowly steeped in fresh coconut puree and gently blended with the chocolate. The taste rushes over you in waves - fragrant curry, chased by coconut, then the lingering, raisiny sweetness of chocolate. Available in</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flavor all cla">
    <h4>Espresso</h4>
    <p>The strong, deep flavors of Ecuadorian Arriba chocolate demand an equally strong flavor companion. Gail uses Just Coffee espresso, made from organic, fair-trade beans here in Madison. Arriba's hint of floral rides lightly atop the earthy espresso and chocolate to fully awaken your taste buds. Available in the</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flavor all tea">
    <h4>Blueberry</h4> 
    <p>This joyful dance begins with dried Michigan blueberries, plumped up in sweet cream infused with Rishi's bright Blueberry Rooibos tea. The blueberries and cream coax out the tangy berry notes of 65% Peruvian chocolate. For texture, Gail adds bits of blueberry. Fresh, pure and bountiful. It's summer and chocolate in a rush of giddy flavor. Available in 
  </div>

  <div class="flavor all tea">
    <img src="images/flavor-earlgrey.jpg" alt="" />
    <h4>Earl Grey</h4> 
    <p>Earl Grey is a deliciously complex experience - orange blossom, bergamot, lavender and black tea. When combined with an intricate 70% dark chocolate blend, the distinctive flavors unfold like the themes in a symphony. It reaches a delirious flavor crescendo and then sends you off with a light floral note of organic lavender buds. Lovely. Available in </p>
  </div>

  <div class="flavor all">
    <img src="images/flavor-fig.jpg" alt="" />
    <h4>Fig</h4> 
    <p>Fresh mission fig puree, grainy and molasses-sweet, pairs well with naturally sweet, 55% Hawaiian dark chocolate. Gail tops with chopped dried figs for a lightly seedy crunch. Let the huge burst of darkly sun-ripened fruit and smooth chocolate transport you.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: А для чего вы использует `class="current"`? Ведь в вашем примере выборка идет по атрибуту `bubu` и соответствующим классам блоков для демонстрации

Comment: Да, точно, тут дело в другом, а именно в selected="selected".  Поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам пример:

```js
$(function() {

var newSelection = ""; 

$(document).on('change', "#flavor-nav",function(){
  $("#all-flavors").fadeTo(200, 0.10);

  $("#flavor-nav option").removeClass("current");
  $("#flavor-nav option:selected").addClass("current");

  newSelection = $("#flavor-nav option:selected").attr("bubu");

  $(".flavor").not("." + newSelection).slideUp();
  $("." + newSelection).slideDown();

  $("#all-flavors").fadeTo(600, 1);
});

});

$( document ).ready(function() {
var defaultEl = $("#flavor-nav").find(':selected');
if (defaultEl.length>0){

var defaultVal = defaultEl.val();
   $("#flavor-nav").val(defaultVal).trigger('change');
   
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="all-flavors">
  <select id="flavor-nav">
    <option bubu="all">All</option> 
    <option bubu="cla" selected="selected">Classic</option> 
    <option bubu="adv">Adventurous</option> 
    <option bubu="tea">Tea-Inspired</option> 
  </select>
  <div class="flavor all adv">
    <h4>Sweet Curry With Saffron</h4>
    <p>Lusciously mellow with notes of overripe berries, 55% Hawaiian dark chocolate meets its soulmate in sweet curry - awash in spices including coriander, tumeric, cumin and cardamom and sprinkled with rare saffron. This spicy melange is slowly steeped in fresh coconut puree and gently blended with the chocolate. The taste rushes over you in waves - fragrant curry, chased by coconut, then the lingering, raisiny sweetness of chocolate. Available in</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flavor all cla">
    <h4>Espresso</h4>
    <p>The strong, deep flavors of Ecuadorian Arriba chocolate demand an equally strong flavor companion. Gail uses Just Coffee espresso, made from organic, fair-trade beans here in Madison. Arriba's hint of floral rides lightly atop the earthy espresso and chocolate to fully awaken your taste buds. Available in the</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flavor all tea">
    <h4>Blueberry</h4> 
    <p>This joyful dance begins with dried Michigan blueberries, plumped up in sweet cream infused with Rishi's bright Blueberry Rooibos tea. The blueberries and cream coax out the tangy berry notes of 65% Peruvian chocolate. For texture, Gail adds bits of blueberry. Fresh, pure and bountiful. It's summer and chocolate in a rush of giddy flavor. Available in 
  </div>

  <div class="flavor all tea">
    <img src="images/flavor-earlgrey.jpg" alt="" />
    <h4>Earl Grey</h4> 
    <p>Earl Grey is a deliciously complex experience - orange blossom, bergamot, lavender and black tea. When combined with an intricate 70% dark chocolate blend, the distinctive flavors unfold like the themes in a symphony. It reaches a delirious flavor crescendo and then sends you off with a light floral note of organic lavender buds. Lovely. Available in </p>
  </div>

  <div class="flavor all">
    <img src="images/flavor-fig.jpg" alt="" />
    <h4>Fig</h4> 
    <p>Fresh mission fig puree, grainy and molasses-sweet, pairs well with naturally sweet, 55% Hawaiian dark chocolate. Gail tops with chopped dried figs for a lightly seedy crunch. Let the huge burst of darkly sun-ripened fruit and smooth chocolate transport you.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! А можете посмотреть еще сейчас, я немного подкорректировал вопрос.

Comment: Подправил под атрибут `selected`

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!!!